# How I set NSAttributedString object to uilabel in xcode4.2 with simulator 5.0?

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I am unable to write following code in xcod4.2 with simulator 5.0 tell me alternate solution

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initwithString:@"This is Green and Red"];
NSDictionary *redatt=@{NSForeGroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]};
NSDictionary *greenatt=@{NSForeGroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]};

[str setAttribute:greenatt range:NSMakeRange(9,5)];
[str setAttribute:redatt range:NSMakeRange(19,3)];

lbl.attributedText=str;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, using code above?

Comment: Did you read the error you got, what did it say?

Comment: Error: UILabel attributedText not available in xcode4.2.

Comment: NSDictionary *greenatt=@{NSForeGroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]}; ....Problem in Version hope so

Comment: I need version specific answer. Same code work on xcode 4.6 with 6.0 simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import **CoreText** Framework and then do it.Try using kCTForegroundColorAttributeName. for more info see in this example

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initwithString:@"This is Green and Red"];


[str addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor] range:NSMakeRange(9,5)];
[str addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor] range:NSMakeRange(19,3)];

lbl.attributedText=str;
```

Comment: @LearnIphone What hpnd bro....

Comment: Try to import like this #import <CoreText/CoreText.h>

Comment: @LearnIphone WHat hpnd bro. Have you got your solution.

Comment: Dear Dharambir : Thanks : for code it work but lbl.attributedText=str; //does not work because uilabel does not has attributedtext property in xcode 4.2 with simulator 5.0 now what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, have tried it worked great:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is Green and Red"] ;

    NSDictionary *redatt=@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[NSColor redColor]};
    NSDictionary *greenatt=@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[NSColor greenColor]};

    [str addAttributes:redatt  range:NSMakeRange(9,5)];
    [str addAttributes:greenatt  range:NSMakeRange(1,4)];

    [lbl.textStorage setAttributedString:str];
```

Comment: [lbl.textStorage setAttributedString:str]; // not worked in xcode4.2 with simulator 5.0 need version specific solution. because uilabel doesnot has textStorage property and setAttributedString Suntion

Comment: have tried in MAC OS, it worked fine thats why suggested.